# MySQL query optimisation when using index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, database-design

I'm busy to optimize and understand the group by function in MySQL. From the answer on SO i learned from Gordon:

> All columns in the select should either be columns in the group by or
>   use aggregate functions (sum(), avg(), and so on).

I have to following table and query

**Table**

```
+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|Id (primary key) | ip(index) | lastattack | create_date |
+-----------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

**Query**

```
  SELECT ip,
         lastattack
    FROM blacklist
   WHERE ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
GROUP BY ip
```

When I execute the above query I receive the following info from **EXPLAIN**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+----------+-------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | ipall | ref  | idx           | idx | 257     |const| 2    | 100.00   | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----+------+----------+-------+
```

When i execute the query like Gordon told me i receive the following in extra

```
  SELECT ip,
         lastattack
    FROM blacklist
   WHERE ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
GROUP BY ip, lastattack
```

> Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

People told me to avoid temporary or filesort.

Comment: What is your rewritten query that you're having the problem with?

Comment: @EdmCoff added the query forgot it during the post

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If i have to put the selected columns in the group by why is mysql explain giving me that temporary and filesort is used. From the answers i read its saying to avoid temporary in your query explain

Answer (score 2):

Your query, as it stands, is incorrect - or rather, it is *ambiguous*. Suppose you have:

```
192.168.0.1    Attack1    2017-10-01 23:30
192.168.0.1    Attack2    2017-10-01 23:35
```

Which value of lastattack should be output? You do not provide enough data to the server, which can't read your mind and surmise that if the field is called "lastattack", you probably want the one with greatest timestamp.

This is what Gordon Linoff was saying - "All columns in the select should either be columns in the GROUP BY, or use aggregate functions"; here, `lastattack` is neither, as you do not GROUP BY lastattack (but only by IP), and you do not aggregate it (you SELECT lastattack, not AVG(lastattack) or SOME_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(lastattack)).

You **might** still get the correct value - but you might not. In practice, records will be retrieved in deterministic order, and chances are that's the order you want. But other DB implementations might fetch the *first* value they encounter and leave you with the first attack instead of the last.

To obtain the result you want, you need first to establish the date of the last attack:

```
SELECT ip, MAX(attackdate) AS maxdate FROM blacklist GROUP BY ip;
```

This gives you a table with the correct timestamps. To get the last attack you need a JOIN (which risks duplicates if two attacks came in the same second, so that you can't determine *which* was the last one):

```
SELECT a.ip, a.maxdate, b.lastattack
    FROM (
        SELECT ip, MAX(attackdate) AS maxdate FROM blacklist GROUP BY ip
    ) AS a
JOIN blacklist AS b ON (a.ip = b.ip AND a.maxdate = b.lastattack)
```

You need an index on `ip` and `attackdate` for the inner query, and that should also work for the outer query. You might want to create an index on `ip`, `attackdate` and `lastattack` in this order to see whether that changes anything.

Comment: why is lastattack neither ? how can I know that this? The lastattack wil always be updated to the latest attack date so there will not be a new record only update

Comment: It is neither because it is not in the GROUP BY (you only group by ip) and it is not in a group function (you don't use, say, MAX(lastattack) or things like that). But *wait*... if lastattack is always updated, does this mean that you have only one row for each IP? If so, why grouping by IP at all?

Comment: What I'm trying is to check if I need to add all the selected colomns in the group by in the first query where i only group the ip its working. But in the second query i use the group by ip and lastattack and when i do this i receive that temporary and filesort is also used by extra but why ? if i only follow the instructions from other database administrators

Comment: The "temporary" warning is due to the fact that the DB needs to gather much more data. And then needs to sort it. The problem is that you **need** to do this, because your incomplete grouping is simpler, faster, but it is only working by chance. Using **a single row per IP** with trigger on update is one solution, and it would allow you to remove the GROUP BY altogether, using a unique index on IP, and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to store the other fields. But it all depends on your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your information and help what i want to try is to create a scenario where i have a table with with indexed column where i explain that i have to put the selected column in group by maybe my test database and query is not the best solution for my question. I want to verify the answer from Gordon that you always have to put the selected column in group by in combination with index to optimize the query.

Comment: Oh, but you do not do that to optimize the query! You organize groups to make the query *work*. Then you design the indexes (and/or restructure the query, use views, use ancillary tables...) to optimize it. You can have one without the other, or both, or neither.